# Trouble passing multi-word argument from bash to expect

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, expect

I have looked at some of the related questions and answers in here, but i'm still stumped :-(

I wish to pass a multi-word command from a bash script to an expect script.  Inside the expect script, the multi-word command will be executed by a send statement.

So, the multi-word command is:

```
get dump perf 0
```

It is stored in the bash script in a variable called `usrcmd`.

The expect script is called like this:

```
./userspecifiedcmd.exp root $password $server $usrcmd
```

In the expect script, the multi-word command is extracted as follows:

```
set usercommand [lrange $argv 3 3]
```

And the multi-word command is executed as follows:  `send "$usercommand\r"`

RESULTS...

The string actually sent by the `send` statement is:  `get`

I have tried putting quotes around the `$usrcmd` variable when I launch the expect script, like this:

```
./userspecifiedcmd.exp root $password $server "$usrcmd"
```

When I do that, the string sent by the send statement is:  `{get dump perf 0}`

My gut tells me there is a simple fix.  Is my gut correct?

Thx!

Comment: Please use backticks to delimit inline code, and select and press the `{}` key in editor to delimit larger pieces (separates them by \n and adds 4 spaces at start of line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expect script *should* be called like this:

```
./userspecifiedcmd.exp root "$password" "$server" "$usrcmd"
```

Always quote your shell variables unless you have a compelling to omit them.

In expect, map the args to variables like this:

```
lassign $argv user password server usercommand
```

The `lrange` command returns a **list**, and when you handle a list like a string, you get the `{}` artifacts. Be aware of your Tcl data types: handle lists as lists, strings as strings. When you have a list, use `join` to "convert" it into a string cleanly.

The Tcl manual pages are helpful: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm
As is the Tcl tutorial: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html

Comment: Thx Glenn.  On the money as usual.  Works like a charm now.  The Tcl tutorial link is now in my "Tools" folder and will be my first stop for answers, going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best solution, but you can do something like this:

```
ls -1 < "echo $(ls a*)"
```

so we are listing all a* things as part of all the files.

In your case,

```
./userspecifiedcmd.exp root $password $server < "echo $usrcmd"
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question in any way.